# How to get grep -F -f to find lines missing from one file in another

Tags: regex, grep

First I create two files:

```
echo -en {1..100..3}"\n" > file1; echo -en {1..100..5}"\n" > file2
```

then

```
grep -v -F -f file1 -- file2 >> file3; cat file3 >> file1; rm file3
```

then

```
grep -v -F -f file2 -- file1 >> file3; cat file3 >> file2; rm file3
```

both `grep -v -F -f file1 -- file2` 
and  `grep -v -F -f file2 -- file1` return nothing

yet numbers like 13, 19, 64, 67, 100 are still only in file1, why?

if you look at the output of `grep -v -F -f file1 -- file2` and 
`grep -v -F -f file2 -- file1` before the merge attempt those numbers are 
also missing

If i use something like `IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in $(cat <file 1>); do ((\!$(grep -F -c -- "$a" <file 2>))) && echo $a; done && unset IFS` it works.

Update the answer is add -x flag to grep for anchoring, thanks to Tripleee:

```
$ echo -en {1..100..3}"\n" > file1; echo -en {1..100..5}"\n" > file2
$ grep -x -v -F -f file1 -- file2 >> file3; cat file3 >> file1; rm file3
$ grep -x -v -F -f file2 -- file1 >> file3; cat file3 >> file2; rm file3
$ grep 13 *
```

file1: 13
file2: 13

before without

```
$ echo -en {1..100..3}"\n" > file1; echo -en {1..100..5}"\n" > file2
$ grep -v -F -f file1 -- file2 >> file3; cat file3 >> file1; rm file3
$ grep -v -F -f file2 -- file1 >> file3; cat file3 >> file2; rm file3
$ grep 13 *
```

file1: 13

Comment: cat <(grep -x -v -F -f file2 -- <((grep -x -v -F -f file1 -- file2) >> file1;cat file1)) >> file2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without anchoring, `grep` will find a match whenever a search pattern is a substring of an input. Add the `-x` option to change that. Then a match will only be reported when the pattern matches the entire input line.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem,                                      $ echo -en {1..100..3}"\n" > file1; echo -en {1..100..5}"\n" > file2
$ grep -x -v -F -f file1 -- file2 >> file3; cat file3 >> file1; rm file3
$ grep -x -v -F -f file2 -- file1 >> file3; cat file3 >> file2; rm file3
$ grep 13 *
file1: 13
file2: 13

Answer (score 1):

Using -w to tell grep to compare words achieve a correct merge.

I did test like this with your exemple files:

```
grep -v -w -f file1 file2 >> file1
grep -v -w -f file2 file1 >> file2
grep -v -w -f file1 file2
```

To be sure I sorted the files:

```
sort -h file1 > f1
sort -h file2 > f2
```

thend a `diff -u f1 f2` giving nothing I ensured it was correct with `diff -y f1 f2`

If you can elaborate on your use case I may improve this answer.

Just in case of, as you're talking about lines in the tittle, the -x flag instead of -w could be what you're looking for.

Comment: I let this in state (been on call and late submission). If it does not add something interesting to @tripleee answer tell me and I'll delete it.

Comment: Huh?  `-f` and `-F` are certainly not incompatible.  The `-F` option specifies how patterns are interpreted (regex vs literal string), not where they can be specified.

Comment: The -w according to the manual does something similar to -x except on a word basis, it works in the example I gave - I was actually looking for whole lines although I didn't state it - I would have given you the credit for this answer if I had seen it first.

Comment: @tripleee oh yes, I forgot about the fixed vs regex, I was thinking about the newline separator -F accept for multiples patterns. You're right and sorry about it.